# How would I create "multiple choice" columns in Local Database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, database

I am using local database for first time with my WPF project. I have the database setup, and I am connecting fine ETC. Ther eare some columns which I want to be multiple choice, either between a few values or a whole bunch of values. Problem is obviously human error will make typos now and then when inputting the data.

How would I go about making the data entry give the user a multiple choice? So for example, I have a column called "Category", and at the moment (this will be expanded later) I only want to allow the following options:
Bronze
Misc

I have the columns set to nvarchar(50) at present, but typing the same string manually constantly... not what I would like to be doing TBH... so... Could I set it so that there are a list of predefined values it will accept? :)

thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CHECK constraint of any complexity on your table column(s). [Check MSDN here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx)
So your table definition would be as:

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
    Category nvarchar(50) CHECK (Category in ('Bronze','Misc'))
)
```

If you expect your list of possible values to change in the future and you do not want to change a table definition, you can create a separate table with the list of values and use the foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE Categories
(
    Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    CategoryName nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO Categories VALUES (1, 'Bronze'), (2, 'Silver'), (3, 'Misc')

CREATE TABLE T
(
    CategoryId int REFERENCES Categories
)
```