# How would I create dropdown list of possible foreign keys?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, database

So, I have a table which has a set number of categories (subject to change in the future). Based on advice from another question ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500450/how-would-i-create-multiple-choice-columns-in-local-database#31500450)), I have created a seperate table which contains a list of the possible categories.

In my main table, I have this column, as an example:

```
[Category] NVARCHAR(50) REFERENCES Categories,
```

I have checked this works - It accepts only values I give in the Categories table correctly.

How would I go about showing the user a dropdown list of possible values here, rather than just give them a big error message when trying to add a row where the foreign key isn't a match?

Comment: I guess you load [Categories] and put them into a ComboBox that does not allow entering custom text.

Comment: Use distinct and fill results into a combobox : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: Where would I do that, and how?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you know connect to db already

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SHARKAWY;Initial Catalog=Booking;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123456"))
{
    try
    {
        string query = "select CategoryName, CategoryID from Categories";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Categories");
        cmbCategories.DisplayMember =  "CategoryName";
        cmbCategories.ValueMember = "CategoryID ";
        cmbCategories.DataSource = ds.Tables["Categories"];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // write exception info to log or anything else
        MessageBox.Show("Error occured!");
    }               
}
```

Comment: I have connected to it already ETC, but I am putting the data into Database from the [Data] window open in visual studio, C# can't go there?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand  `putting the data into Database from the [Data] window` if data is on database this bring it back. You also could use EF instead.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/H4I5ldr.png << Thats where I am inputting the data, so the Category column there I want to have a dropdown box with possible values. And whats EF?

Comment: Then your data is already on DB. That is just an Database Data Editor Embeded in Visual Studio.

Comment: Here is an [Entity Framework (EF)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhUPBSX-E2aJCnCR3-_6zBZx) tutorial

Comment: Just follow this code and let me know if there is something you dont understand

Comment: So would ther ebe a way to have the database data editor embedded in VS show a dropdown box for me? Would EF do that?There is some data there, but I want to be adding lots more records via that data editor...

Comment: I dont think so. You will need create your own dataentry form. I suggest you rewrite your question or create a new one because that is not what you ask here.